# Tomcat 7, JSF 2.0 and @PostConstruct

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, please help:

1. Fresh Tomcat 7 with no extra jars in /lib folder
2. Simple web-app with mojarra 2.0.3 libs in WEB-INF/lib (jsf-api.jar, jsf-impl.jar)
3. Works fine except @PostConstruct in my beans - they're not called at all

Logs:

```
Mar 12, 2011 11:19:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive test_web_app.war
Mar 12, 2011 11:19:54 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.3 (FCS b03) for context '/test_web_app'
Mar 12, 2011 11:19:54 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
           version="3.0">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
              version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```

Bean with unreachable method:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppBean {

  @PostConstruct
  public void test() {
    throw new RuntimeException("test");
  }
}
```

That's all. Any ideas?

Comment: The whole stack trace would help. With some quick googling I suspect that's not the problem.

Comment: @Brian Roach, actually the whole stack is  'Mar 12, 2011 11:19:54 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.3 (FCS b03) for context '/test_web_app'
' before the line I mentioned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your application scoped managed bean is not used on any pages, you have to annotate it with

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
```

in order to get it initialized on startup.

Answer (score 0):

@PostConstruct should be work if beans is loaded, you can load it when directly call or using eager=true, or do init in constructor.